Conflicting Solutions for Calculating Apparent Speed of Jogger's Image in Convex Mirror
I’m facing a challenge with a physics problem due to conflicting solutions across different sources, and I'd appreciate some clarification.
Problem Statement:
Suppose, while sitting in a parked car, you notice a jogger approaching you in the side-view mirror with a radius of curvature =2m. If the jogger is running at 5m/s, how fast does the image of the jogger appear to move when the jogger is at distances of:
a) 39 m
b) 29 m
c) 19 m
d) 9 m from the mirror?
Different Sources and Solutions:
Vedantu’s Solution (https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/suppose-while-sitting-in-a-parked-car-you-notice-class-12-physics-cbse-5f5586521af3d7476bafd7cd): This solution seems to involve a particular approach to differentiation with respect to the mirror formula, but the final answer differs from other sources.
Doubtnut’s Solution (https://www.doubtnut.com/qna/12010875): Doubtnut presents a slightly different approach, with yet another distinct answer, which adds to the confusion.
Sarthaks Solution (https://www.sarthaks.com/1940263/suppose-while-sitting-parked-notice-jogger-approaching-towards-view-mirror-jogger-running): Sarthaks also offers a different method and answer, which diverges from the previous two sources.
My Attempt:



    
    
    Physics Problem


    I tried solving it by differentiating the mirror formula:
1/f = 1/v + 1/u
with respect to time. Here, d/dt = 5 m/s (the jogger’s speed), and f = +1 m for the mirror. Despite careful calculations, my results also differ from these resources.
Could someone provide a definitive solution for the apparent speed of the image and clarify why these variations might exist across different solutions?
Thank you for any guidance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
